# How to format external drive into ZFS?

Tags: zfs

I've installed MacZFS in 10.9.5 successfully, but I don't know how to simply format the external drive into ZFS on OSX. I'm confused with zpools, can anybody explains what are the zpools and how to format the drive?

My drive is: /dev/disk3.

diskutil partitiondisk /dev/disk3 GPTFormat ZFS %noformat% 100%

This command running successfully but the next command

zpool create extdrive /dev/disk3s2

is not working properly, showing error :

cannot open '/dev/disk3s2': Permission denied

internal error: Unknown error: -22

Abort trap: 6

Answer (score 0):

You need to be root to create a ZFS pool:

```
sudo zpool create extdrive /dev/disk3s2
```

Edit:

`Error -22` looks to be an undocumented OS X error, might be either an hardware or a software issue. See [this page](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/i-got-the-same-error-text-only-with-22.1833387/) for example.

Comment: Still there is an error - internal error: Unknown error: -22

Comment: I have no idea and no h/w to investigate. You might use dtrace to identify where the command fails.

Comment: Can you tell me the signature bytes of zfs file system to identify a drive is formatted in zfs or not ?

Comment: You migth search for the überblock magic number (00bab10c). See for example http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/ZFS_forensics_scrollback_script

Comment: Can you tell me the  vdev disk structure of zfs ?

Comment: I don't get your question.

Comment: How data (file/folder) can be traced in zfs file system? My disk has EFI label  not VTOC.